# How to load a css class in a url ? Is it possible to do so?

Tags: javascript, css, url

I have a login modal that loads via CSS class , so for example, if I give my button that class and click the button it loads the login modal.. cool, now that login modal has no direct URL to load which is weird!! Is there any possible way to make a URL which is able to load that css class when put in the browser?

Comment: You seem to be confusing "CSS classes" (which don't exist) with HTML classes … and JavaScript with weirdness. It's very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Hahahahaha, because it is not possible. Bro what I’m sayin is I have a Wordpress plugin that makes its login launch via .lrm-login class ...... on my home page, I can simply add that class to a button and it will trigger the login popup. On my forums However, when a user tries to add a new topics and asks them to login and takes them to the forum login page , not the same login pop up on my home page .. now what URL shall I put for my forum login link ??? Again I have only a .class from that login plugin and not a direct URL that can load the login pop up

Comment: When your button is clicked, a JavaScript click event listener bound to the `.lrm-login` class invokes the modal. If you want to show the modal on page load, I'd suggest adding a query string parameter or hash (`?login` or `#login`) to your URL, and write some JavaScript to check for the presence of such a token in the URL on page load, invoking the modal if found. At the moment, there's insufficient information in your post to be able to advise further.

Comment: Have tried botth ?login and #login and didn’t work , which is also weird because when I hover over the login button with that class it shows on the url description at bottom exactly that: #login ... but when I type #login the the browser it doesn’t load ..

Comment: The presence of `#login` in the URL doesn't mean the plugin included JavaScript code to do what you want. It might simply be there as a page anchor. You're going to need to post your code outlining a minimal, viable example for anyone here to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

With the little information that is provided, you should be able to trigger the clicking of your `lrm-login` button on page load if the url has `#login`.

```
if(document.location.hash == "#login"){
    document.getElementsByClassName('lrm-login')[0].click();
}
```

Comment: Where would that line go

Comment: Try adding it at the bottom of your page wrapped in `<script>` tags or in a file that is loaded.